# SelectedItem in ComboBox not being set to data field

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, wpf-controls

For some reason the SelectedItem is not getting set to whatever the field in the database is.

XAML:

```
            <!-- Type -->
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                   Style="{StaticResource FormLabelStyle}"
                   Content="Type:"/>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                    Style="{StaticResource FormBorderStyle}"
                    Width="350">
                <ComboBox x:Name="codeType" Margin="5" Padding="0"
                          FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial" BorderThickness="0"
                          BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="White"
                          Text="{Binding CodType}" SelectedItem="{Binding CodType}">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="C"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="C++"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="C#"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="PL/SQL"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="SQL"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="HTML"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="XAML"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Unix Shell Script"/>
                </ComboBox>
            </Border>
```

Code Behind:

```
public ChangeCode(CodeRecord codRec)
{
    _codeRecord = codRec;
    this.DataContext = _codeRecord;

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

When the screen is shown I want the current CodType field to be selected. Debugging shows that it is indeed not null and is one of the comboboxitems. The combobox shows nothing selected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: would you mind sharing the code of CodeRecord? ChangeCode is the window class I believe?

Answer (score 0):

When you create ComboBoxItem the content text is string, string class doesn't have a property for displaying the Text, it may allow you to select by using the string.ToString() but when the screen is shown it doesn't have a property to match to the ComboBox items and display what is in the SelectedValue. In order to solve it you must create a new class ComboBoxItemString as below with a property ValueString

```
public class ComboBoxItemString
{
    public string ValueString { get; set; }
}
```

Then create an array (CodeTypesList) of ComboBoxItemString in the resources as shown below and bind it to ItemsSource and then use the poperty ValueString in the DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
        Style="{StaticResource FormBorderStyle}"
        Width="350">
    <Border.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="CodTypesList" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString">
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "C"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "C++"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "C#"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "PL/SQL"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "SQL"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "HTML"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "XAML"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Unix Shell Script"/>
        </x:Array>
    </Border.Resources>
    <ComboBox x:Name="codeType" Margin="5" Padding="0"
              FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial" BorderThickness="0"
              BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="White" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding CodType}"
              ItemsSource="{StaticResource CodTypesList}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="ValueString" SelectedValuePath="ValueString" />
</Border>
```

Now, when you come into the screen it should use the property to show the previously selected value in the ComboBox

Comment: I have implemented (almost) your solution. However, I can't get the changes to compile. I get an error, "The type reference cannot find a public type named 'ComboBoxItemString'. This is the c# code for the class. "namespace ws
{
    public class ComboBoxItemString
    {
        public string ValueString { get; set; }
    }
}"  Since it is in the namespace, I don't understand why it cannot see it. How do you format code in the comments?

Comment: You need to add the XML namespace of your project to the XAML and then it'll see the type reference `<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ws"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">` Here is where I am adding `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ws"` , make sure to use the same prefix 'local' when you refer ComboBoxItemString array `<local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString="C"/>`

Comment: To format code in comments use the grave accent/backtick character \`your code\`. It is the key above the tab key, and the key left of the number 1 and ! key in [US keyboard layout](https://www.microsoft.com/enable/images/products/kbqwerty.gif)

Comment: Okay. I got it to compile but the combo box still doesn't show anything selected when I come into the screen. Do I need to add code to the get and set properties?

Comment: use `SelectedValue="{Binding CodType}"` instead of `SelectedItem`

Comment: It works! I want to thank you for your insight into this interesting challenge. I have indeed learned a lot. About properties, comboboxes and xaml.  Thanks again.

Comment: you are very welcome and also don't forget to mark the solution as answer, it'll help others to find it easily